# Google SSO aouth 2.0 gives Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed.'

Tags: php, codeigniter, single-sign-on, google-oauth

I have sign in with google enable in my website it is working fine since last 3-4 month but from yesterday it start giving me following error on every 4-5 minuites

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message
>   'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Code was
>   already redeemed.'' in
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\domain.com\src\Google\Client.php(131):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('4/8hj0saqecCytQ...', false) #1
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\domain.com\application\libraries\NV_gmail.php(105):
>   Google_Client->authenticate('4/8hj0saqecCytQ...') #2
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\domain.com\application\libraries\layout.php(51):
>   NV_gmail->login() #3
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\tl-l.com\application\controllers\dashboard.php(19):
>   layout->header() #4 [internal function]: dashboard->index() #5
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\domain.com\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\domain.com\index.php(202):
>   require_once('F:\ServerFolder...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   F:\ServerFolders\Projects\domain.com\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on
>   line 126

And shows blank page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

to

```
 //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

from curl.php according to [github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/639](http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/639) and now working fine

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks authenticate you are given an authentication code.  You take this code and exchange it for your access token and refresh token.

> 'invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed

Means that you are taking an authentication code that has already been used and trying to get another access token / refresh token for it.

If it has worked for the last 4 months my opinion is that someone changed something in your code and broke it.

Comment: currently it is working but gives this error on every 4-5 minute interval.

Comment: Check your code then there is probably someplace in there that occasionally it try's to send it again.

Comment: Comment curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
from curl.php according to https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/639 and now working fine.thanks for your help